# Timeout issue with building environment for KoBo Toolbox on VPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, kobo, kobotoolbox

I’ve set up my KoBo Toolbox server on a Ubuntu v20.04 VPS with 8gb RAM and 320GB of storage. I’ve gotten to the final stage of the installation where it’s setting up the environment and then it times out after 600s, there are no errors, my DNS is all enabled and pings correctly, I can’t find the error. Can anyone help?

> ```
> > kobo@vps-6f095bcb:~/kobo-install$ ./run.py Stopping
> > nginx-certbot_nginx_ssl_proxy_1 ... done Stopping
> > nginx-certbot_certbot_1         ... done Stopping kobofe_nginx_1      
> > ... done Stopping kobofe_kpi_1            ... done Stopping
> > kobofe_kobocat_1        ... done Stopping kobofe_enketo_express_1 ...
> > done Removing network kobomaintenance_kobo-maintenance-network
> > WARNING: Network kobomaintenance_kobo-maintenance-network not found.
> > Removing network kobofe_kobo-fe-network Removing
> > nginx-certbot_nginx_ssl_proxy_1 ... done Removing
> > nginx-certbot_certbot_1         ... done Removing network
> > kobofe_kobo-fe-network WARNING: Network kobofe_kobo-fe-network not
> > found. Removing network nginx-certbot_default Stopping
> > kobobe_redis_main_1  ... done Stopping kobobe_mongo_1       ... done
> > Stopping kobobe_redis_cache_1 ... done Stopping kobobe_postgres_1   
> > ... done Removing kobobe_redis_main_1  ... done Removing
> > kobobe_mongo_1       ... done Removing kobobe_redis_cache_1 ... done
> > Removing kobobe_postgres_1    ... done Removing network
> > kobobe_kobo-be-network Removing kobofe_nginx_1          ... done
> > Removing kobofe_kpi_1            ... done Removing kobofe_kobocat_1   
> > ... done Removing kobofe_enketo_express_1 ... done Removing network
> > kobofe_kobo-fe-network WARNING: Network kobofe_kobo-fe-network not
> > found. Removing network kobobe_kobo-be-network WARNING: Network
> > kobobe_kobo-be-network not found. Launching environment Creating
> > network "kobobe_kobo-be-network" with driver "bridge" Creating
> > kobobe_mongo_1       ... done Creating kobobe_postgres_1    ... done
> > Creating kobobe_redis_main_1  ... done Creating kobobe_redis_cache_1
> > ... done Waiting for PostgreSQL database to be up & running...
> > Creating network "kobofe_kobo-fe-network" with driver "bridge"
> > Creating kobofe_kpi_run ... done The PostgreSQL database is running!
> > Creating kobofe_kpi_run ... done Creating kobofe_kobocat_1        ...
> > done Creating kobofe_enketo_express_1 ... done Creating kobofe_kpi_1  
> > ... done Creating kobofe_nginx_1          ... done Creating network
> > "nginx-certbot_default" with the default driver Creating
> > nginx-certbot_certbot_1         ... done Creating
> > nginx-certbot_nginx_ssl_proxy_1 ... done Waiting for environment to be
> > ready. It can take a few minutes.
> > ............................................................
> > `KoBoToolbox` has not started yet. This is can be normal with low
> > CPU/RAM computers.
> > 
> > Wait for another 600 seconds?   1) Yes  2) No [1]: 1
> > ............................................................
> > `KoBoToolbox` has not started yet. This is can be normal with low
> > CPU/RAM computers.
> > 
> > Wait for another 600 seconds?
> ```

I was following this [guide](https://community.kobotoolbox.org/t/kobo-install-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-lts-vps/3250) to set it up and everything is running as would be expected except instead of finishing setting up the environment it times out, my server has more than the minimum requirements and everything seems to be set up correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bumping this up